# Help with opend id and associated accounts

Tags: support, openid

I have account using google openid on stackoverflow, meta and superuser.

It happens that, for some reason I don't know/don't recall, my superuser account username is quite ridiculous: something similar to user13412

And I would like to change that. I would like to be nunos on all three sites.

My question is, how can I clear the association or possibly the userxxxxx account. I really don't mind loosing the reputation on superuser since it's not that much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Super User, go to your profile and click the `Edit` link while logged in. Change the field marked `Display Name` to whatever you want. No reputation loss needed; all usernames are modifiable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "clear associations" button on the accounts tab of your user page?

You can also use the "copy profile" button there as well.

Comment: I am getting the same problem... some accounts will re-link, but others will say "user Id #### already associated with another account". Its kind of a one-way re-association for some reason.

Comment: @talvi you need to click "clear associations"; this also implies you might possibly have one or more duplicate accounts

Comment: I tried this a second time, same thing. So I tried a third and then it worked for all but one. I went to *that* user account, cleared associations, then relinked. It had them all on SO, but not the associated ones, until I finally did "copy profile". Now they seem linked. Possibly the "clear all" function is partially faulted somewhere?